# SQL Error in Non Case condition of CASE WHEN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I tried executing the following SQL statement.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('~','test.pdf') > 0 
            THEN SUBSTRING('test.pdf',CHARINDEX('~', 'test.pdf'), -10)
            ELSE NULL
       END
```

This resulted in an error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the substring function.'. However, this was not expected because it is not going to execute anyway.

This query is a simplified version of my requirement. Actually we are computing the value length for the substring. The real scenario is also given below :

```
SELECT CASE
            WHEN CHARINDEX('~', 'test.pdf') > 0 THEN SUBSTRING('test.pdf', CHARINDEX('~', 'test.pdf') + 1, CHARINDEX('~', 'test.pdf', (CHARINDEX('~', 'test.pdf', 1)) + 1) - CHARINDEX('~', 'test.pdf') - 1)
            ELSE NULL
       END;
```

In the example its hardcoded as 'test.pdf' but in real scenario it would be values like '111111~22222~33333~4444.pdf' from Table column. Also, I'm not sure this file name should always follow this format. Hence, a validation is required.

**Actually, the computation for length is quite expensive, and don't want to use it twice in this query.**

Comment: The length parameter is negative, which is rather unorthodox.  Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to do would help.

Comment: Side note, `ELSE NULL` in a `CASE` **expression** is actually redundant. If none of the `WHEN` clauses are fulfilled then a `CASE` will automatically return `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated the question as you suggested. Thank You

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please provide a good sample data and the desired results as _formatted text_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have passed `-10` as a constant to `substring()`.  [This function does not allow negative values for the third argument:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> length
>
> Is a positive integer or bigint expression that specifies how many characters of the expression will be returned. If length is negative, an error is generated and the statement is terminated. If the sum of start and length is greater than the number of characters in expression, the whole value expression beginning at start is returned.

SQL Server catches this problem during the compile phase.  This has nothing to do with `CASE` expression evaluation, but with *parsing* the expressions.

Comment: -10 was only to illustrate the issue. In the second query it was computed.

Comment: @SubinJacob . . . If the length is an expression, it is not checked at compile time and you don't get the error.

Comment: Then, I did it wrong, testing this query with hardcoded filename value. Actually, it wouldn't be the case if  it was a table column, right? We were not supposed to insert any value to the table, thats why tested like this